# Python Pyodbc Binary Column is returning \xda\x08\xcd\x08\xba\x08 instead of numbers

Tags: python, sql, type-conversion, pyodbc, varbinary

I have a SQL database that displays a varbinary (max) like this 0x9406920691068F... I want to import it to python pycharm to get the same exact type of data. 
However, it shows something like this instead
[b'\x94\x06\x92\x06\x91\x06\x8f\x06\x8d..
how do I copy the same numbers to python? I am a beginner in python, please help.

I copied the code from previous post and it didn't work

```
import pyodbc

    def hexToString(binaryString):
    try:
      hashString = ["{0:0>2}".format(hex(b)[2:].upper()) for b in binaryString]
      return '0x' + "".join(hashString)
    except:
      return binaryString


    query = """ select P from Access.table """

conn_str = (
      **** private database details # I don't copy on the page
    )

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_BINARY, hexToString)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute(query)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
except MySQLdb.error as err:
    print(err)
else:
    while row is not None:
        print(row)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column return type is `varbinary(max)` then you need to add the output converter function to handle `SQL_VARBINARY`, not `SQL_BINARY`

```
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_VARBINARY, converter_function_name)
```

Comment: And also, if you could help, if I want to convert into floating point numbers, would that be better to do it in HEX bytes or varbinary(max) ?

Comment: @RCan - I'm not sure what you mean. Take a `varbinary`-like column and interpret it as `float` (or similar)? In any case, that would be a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).